# Marketing Cloud - Image appears broken in cloudpages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a cloud page which renders a contenblock as shown below and
is set to work only with HTTPS (*the option chosen during the building of the cloud page*)

```
%%[
VAR @contentBlockID
set @contentBlockID = "4179901"
]%%

%%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%
```

This HTML content block has an image and some text as shown below

```
    <span style="font-size:12pt">
      
    <p>
      <br>
      Thanks for your response.
      <br>
           
    <br>
    </span>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<img data-assetid="408384" src="http://image.xyz.com.au/lib/fe8c13727650017573/m/4/f7a93aac-4287-4f97-bc72-788955e57145.png" alt="" height="51" width="150" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: left; height: 51px; width: 150px; border: 0px;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="background:white"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif"><b><span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:10.0pt"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="color:#492365">T. </span></span></span></b><span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:10.0pt"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="color:#666666">1300 300 300</span></span></span></span></span></span></span><br>
    <span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="background:white"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif"><b><span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:10.0pt"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="color:#492365">E.</span></span></span></b> <span lang="EN-GB" style="color:black"><a href="mailto:mail@xyz.com.au"><span style="font-size:10.0pt"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="color:#1155cc">mail@xyz.com.au</span></span></span></a></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><br>
    <span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="background:white"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif"><b><span lang="EN-GB" style="font-size:10.0pt"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="color:#492365">W.</span></span></span></b> <span lang="EN-GB" style="color:black"><a href="http://www.xyz.com.au/"><span style="font-size:10.0pt"><span style="line-height:115%"><span style="color:#1155cc">www.xyz.com.au</span></span></span></a></span></span></span></span></span><br>
    &nbsp;
```

When it actually renders though, the image looks broken as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

When I did an inspect and copied the element, I observe that the image is sourced from "http" version of our website instead of "https" as shown below

```
<img data-assetid="408384" src="http://image.xyz.com.au/lib/fe8c13727650017573/m/4/f7a93aac-4287-4f97-bc72-788955e57145.png" alt="" height="51" width="150" style="display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: left; height: 51px; width: 150px; border: 0px;">
```

This image was uploaded as an asset in content builder and I would like to know why this upload went as "http" upload.

How do we fix this so that the image appears in the cloudpage ?

Comment: Did you buy SSL for images?

Comment: Also I don’t see the `img` tag in the content block you provided

Comment: @zuzannamj I have updated the code block. Thanks for pointing it out. Also if we purchase SSL for the images, will this issue be resolved ?

Comment: So the original image is http not https - is it hosted in Marketing Cloud or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ContentBuilder is storing images without https is because you haven't enabled the SSL in the SFMC account.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NTecJ0A8_8
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387921&type=1

Comment: Can you post the steps for how to enable it here? Or other relevant key points from the video? Links to other content are fine, but they can break so it pays to have the details here too.